# The firewall cache is difficulting my react app functionality

Tags: caching, configuration, firewall, browser-cache

My firewall provider has a developer mode (with 0 cache even static files) and my web works well in this mode however when I am in a different mode everything is a mess, the thing is If I use developer mode I have to add every ip manually so it´s not practical or functional at all. So my question is, Do all firewalls providers need cache in order to function?, What do you recommend in a situation like mine?.